# How to use headers from subproject in workspace? [PICTURE]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, amazon-web-services

I have an a project called azadi and i want to use the header files from another xcode project. I figured the best way to make it easy to do so was to create a workspace and add both projects to it.

I've dragged both projects into one workspace, but i can't reference any files from S3.xcodeproj in Azadi.xcodeproj.

What am i missing?

[image: My workspace]

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what kind of project you have added, but let's assume **project2** is a static library.

In the description of the steps below I assume **project1** is your primary project, and **project2** is the one containing functionality needed by **project1**

First of all, don't drop **project2** in the workspace. Drop it inside **project1**

Then follow those steps:

1) Select the **project2** project and select "Build phases" in the top.

2) Expand "Copy Headers"

3) Select all files except the "*.pch" file.

4) Create a folder in **project1** called "Indexed Headers" and drag the selected files to this folder.
Make sure that "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" and "Add to targets" are both unchecked.
Click "Finish." (*Note:this step is needed to get autocompletion working properly*)

5) Now select your Xcode project in the top of the project navigator.

6) Select "Build phases" Expand "Target dependencies" and click the "+"

8) Select "**project2**" and click "Add" Expand "Link Binary With Libraries" and click the "+"

9) Select "**project2**" and click "Add"

You're done! Your project should now build when you hit Cmd+B